# Fined €110 for Schengen overstay: impact on future visas?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, overstaying

I miscalculated the number of days I would be in the Schengen region for a conference, and was fined 110 euros for overstaying by a day. Will I be refused a Schengen visa in future on account of this? I am an Indian national and was traveling on a business visa.

Comment: Any particular reason for overstay?

Comment: Can you tell us your nationality and some more details.

Comment: Indian Nationality, miscalculated the no:of days.

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to tell if you will get a visa in the future or not. Your overstay would only be *one* factor in the equation. However, regardless of whether it is formally considered during the decision or not, an overstay be a *single day* should not be a show-stopper on its own.

Answer (score 1):

The top story on https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/permalink/post/17975501 is about someone overstaying by 4 days, paying a fine and then two days later entering a few days later without problems.

If your story is correct and you were let go with just paying a fine and you were not deported then you should be fine. If, on the hand, you got the  giant red deportation stamp in your passport you are hosed: not only in the EU but every country you attempt to enter will consider twice before letting you in.

Comment: Note that the thread in question is four years old, before the 90/180 calculation change (see http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/21461/19400).  Other procedures could have changed in the meanwhile.